# Is it safe to store token in browser local storage after web api authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I am building angular js 1.X application using Asp.net Web API 2  for backend. In web API 2 i can easily get Token by posting my credentials on token end point (ApplicationOAuthProvider) . 
Now as angular JS is client side so i need a place on client side to save this token so that i can send this token in all subsequent HTTP calls to validate client .
For this i am have stored my token on local storage of browser .But i am not that is it safe to store token here (Client side).
As anyone having access to my system can easily get token and use it on his machine to login system. 
If anyone has suggestion then please guide me .Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the fundamental challenges of authentication in web applications.  The short answer is, "It's good enough."

The longer answer is that you should verify that:

1. The token is sufficiently long to prevent brute forcing
2. The token is sufficiently random to prevent guessing
3. The communication is *always* over TLS to prevent interception/sniffing

For comprehensive best practices, you ought to spend some time at the [OWASP](http://owasp.org) site.

Comment: What if one uses http only cookies to store token info

Comment: That is a good practice as well, but it will not protect you if they are not random, long, and sent over a secure channel.  That will only protect you against cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: As you mentioned it should be enough long to prevent brute forcing.  As i am using  .net ApplicationOAuthProvider ,it authomaticaly encrypt token to a long encrypted string  .

Comment: As you mentioned it should be enough long to prevent brute forcing.  As i am using  .net ApplicationOAuthProvider ,it automatically encrypt token to a long encrypted string  .So its already safe against Brute force attack.
My point is if someone copy this token from my machine either by manually accessing or by other wat then he does not need to decryption as he directly can get access by just passing this token in header of request on any random machine.
Is there any way if someone post this token from another machine (Not that machine to which it was generated) .

Comment: Unless you are going to implement client side certificates stored on smart cards, there's nothing that you can do about that, @tajindersingh